# What is difference between Core NLP and Stanford NLP?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Can anybody let me know the difference between Core NLP

http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/

and Stanford NLP

http://nlp.stanford.edu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my knowledge, the group at Stanford University works on different NLP mechanisms, out of which CoreNLP is the major one. Thus core NLP is nothing but a product outcome of Stanford NLP team research & contributions.

Answer (score 0):

Stanford NLP is a group which has developed core NLP components  like **Tokenization , Sentence Detection ,POS Tagging , and NER , Entity Linking and Annotation** for Training those modules etc ..

stanford core components related to NLP are coming under **CoreNLP**
http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/

Answer (score 0):

Right now they have STANZA in python, since Stanford NLP is Java.

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/

> Release History 
>   Note that prior to version 1.0.0, the Stanza library
>   was named as “StanfordNLP”. To install historical versions prior to to
>   v1.0.0, you’ll need to run pip install stanfordnlp.

Answer (score 0):

**Core NLP** is a product outcome by the **Stanford NLP** research and development team. Stanford develop core NLP components such as tokenizing, Sentence Detection.,POS Tagging components. Therefore there is no much difference between the two terms.
***Simply Core NLP is a synonym of Standford NLP.***